# Character pointer in sscanf()

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Can I use a character pointer (`char *`) as the output string in the `sscanf()` function? Take into consideration I don't know the length of the string (that's why I am using pointer).

```
char *name;
sscanf(data, "Name:%[^\t\n]", name);
```

Comment: A pointer should point to somewhere..

Comment: No.  `sscanf()` requires that the arguments that are pointers to `char` point to the first character of an array, and that array is large enough to hold whatever will be written to it.

Comment: If you are using `sscanf()` then you will know the length of its input string before processing it, hence the maximum length of the output (argument) string.

Comment: `scanf` has no "output string". You have to provide the **array** for the "string" by passing a pointer to its first element. The documentation of `scanf` can be found by a simple search, or even in your IDE or OS (e.g. on Linux with `man 3 scanf`). Not sure what your problem is. See [ask], provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a char-pointer to extract a string from another, but this char-pointer shall be allocated with enough space.

> The format specifier shall be ending by one specifier (here is missing 's' for a
>   string).

```
char name[MAX_LENGTH+1]; // allocate enough characters

sscanf(data, "%[^\t\n]s", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use. when the argument is an array, the base address of the array is passed to the sscanf function. passing a pointer to the sscanf is as good as passing an array name(array base address).